# Blender 2.93 won't work on raspbian buster

Tags: rendering, installation, linux

I tried to install blender 2.93 on a raspberry pi 4b running raspbian buster, but I only can get version v2.78b, and I can't install the zip file for linux downloaded from the blender website. I need at least v2.80 or newer. Any answers would help.

Answer (score 2):

It's impossible, 2.80 requires OpenGL 3.3 at least, while Raspberry Pi 4 can support only 2.1:

https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=244520